# Can I access the console Command line API (like $$ and traceAll from Firebug or Chrome Inspector Console) from an external javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, console, command, firebug

Is it possible to access the [Command Line Api](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API) from an external api?

*Simple Example:*

HTML

```
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
  <script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

myScript.js

```
$$('#myDiv').textContent = 'this will not work';
```

I do not wan't to load an external library like jQuery or Zepto because seens like this is already loaded locally.

Comment: What if the command line isn't available in someone's browser? These commands will fail. I think they're separate for a reason

Comment: If this capability existed, it would be a huge security hole, as commands entered into the Command Line Api are pasted into the page, and evaluated using eval(). This would allow a malicious site to run a script-injection and gain access to the browser's session information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, no. But I don't think you really want to. The API may change, breaking your code. If all you're looking for is the query selector. I think you are better off using a snippet found on the MDN.

```
function $ (selector, el) {
    if (!el) {el = document;}
    return el.querySelector(selector);
}
function $$ (selector, el) {
    if (!el) {el = document;}
    return el.querySelectorAll(selector);
    // Note: the returned object is a NodeList.
    // If you'd like to convert it to a Array for convenience, use this instead:
    // return Array.prototype.slice.call(el.querySelectorAll(selector));
}
alert($('#myID').id);
```

[Document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector)